# m2crypto generated certificate file "This file is invalid for use as the following: security certificate" error

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, m2crypto

My python application is using M2Crypto to generate CSR in client, sends it to server and retrieves signed certificate in PEM format and saves as file.

Signed certificate file can be verified by M2Crypto. It can be read by OpenSSL successfully both in client and server.

However Windows clients report "`This file is invalid for use as the following: security certificate`" error when it is tried to be used. Like wise, in Ubuntu clients, "`Could not display <filename>`" is reported when it is tried to be viewed.

Platform Information for both client and server:

- Python 2.7.x
- M2Crypto 0.21.1
- OpenSSL 1.0.1e

Do you have any idea, what am I missing?

Comment: In Windows, I assume you get the error message if you rename it to `.csr` and open it? Have you tried viewing the file using a text editor? Is the file saved as ASCII file?

Comment: I don't think it is related with extension, I have tried many ways to import and all failed. Also please note file is read by OpenSSL without any problem. When I view file in text editor; it seems a proper PEM file, starting with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ending with  `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. Its encoding was UTF-8, I have converted to ANSI, the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a real idea then - but try this: Check the certificate with the command `openssl x509 -in <cert.pem> -text -noout` and see if you notice something strange.

Comment: I have solved the problem. It was due to missing serial field of certificate. Details are here: https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto/issues/12